# Find X location using 3 known (X,Y) location using trilateration

Tags: trilateration

trying to **understand the maths** behind trilateration, we have 3 access points (AP 1,2,3)  and we know the centre coordinates of theses 3 (AP). Lost device (X) is the location where all 3 circle intersect.

example GRID = x=30, y=30.

Known Locations: **AP1 = (5,5), AP2 = (5,15), AP3 = (20,10)**.

Unknown Location: X

*Lets say X = (9,11)*

how do we work out the intersection of all 3 circles by the maths.

your help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Here i am trying it on graph paper]

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/ ...?

Comment: I have move the question to [here][1] (math.stackexchange.com)


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884807/find-x-location-using-3-known-x-y-location-using-trilateration